# C: Is there a way to avoid duplication of code in the given line?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

the following simple program takes in values of cost price and selling price from the user and tells whether the user profited or lost, and by how much:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        float c, s;
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter the CP and SP, separated by space: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%f %f", &c, &s);
        fprintf(stdout, "You %s %.2f.\n", (s > c ? "profited" : "lost"), ((s - c) > 0 ? (s - c) : -1 * (s - c)));
        return 0;
}
```

In the line `fprintf(stdout, "You %s %.2f.\n", (s > c ? "profited" : "lost"), ((s - c) > 0 ? (s - c) : -1 * (s - c)));` Can the expression `((s - c) > 0 ? (s - c) : -1 * (s - c))` be phrased differently to avoid needing to calculate `s - c` twice? I know I can always do this:

```
x = s - c;
...x > 0 ? x : -x
```

but that's not what I want.

Comment: The built-in `abs` function?

Comment: I could always use `fabs` from math.h... thx!

Comment: Yes, `abs()` takes `int` arguments, but `fabs()` takes `double`s, which will work for you.  You need to `#include <math.h>` to get its declaration, and you probably need to link the math library to your program to use it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just pre-compute `c - s` and store it in a variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger wanted to think of an alternative as mentioned in my question. thx anyway!

Comment: use fabs**f** for floats